# Opacity Loop in jQuery

Tags: jquery, animation, opacity

I have two images in a stack, say #a and #b. b's opacity is 1 and I want when I hover my mouse over it, it will start animating opacity from 0 to 1 and than 1 to 0. In this way this loop will be continued until mouse goes out of the image.

You can find a similar thing here: http://www.myhabit.com/#page=b&dept=women&sale=A3RT7N8JLFHTE3&ref=qd_g_cur_img_b

I am new in jQuery.

Comment: Show us the code you have so far. An [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) such as a http://jsfiddle.net demo would be extremely helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var cancel = false;

$("#b").hover(function() {
    var fadeDirection = 0;

    var next = function(jqo) {
        if(cancel) {
            jqo.stop(true);
            jqo.fadeIn(); // <-- not the neatest but I don't know another way to make it compatible
            jqo.stop(false, true);
        }

        if(fadeDirection = 1 - fadeDirection) {
            jqo.fadeIn(function() { next(jqo); });
        } else {
            jqo.fadeOut(function() { next(jqo); });
        }
    };

    next($(this));
}, function() {
    cancel = true;
});
```

Something like that?